# Where can download apache kylin odbc driver?

Tags: odbc, tableau-api, kylin

I tried to integrate Tableau BI with Apache Kylin through ODBC way. Then visited the official website to get the ODBC driver, but found that it was doesn't provide installation file download. Only tell us to compile it from the source code by yourself. But I can't do it, so is there someone can help me or tell where I can find the driver download?

Answer (score 3):

Here you can request the download from Kyligence website: 
https://kyligence.io/resources/kyligence-odbc-driver-for-apache-kylin-2/.

Comment: That's great. Thanks.